# How to mix env variables with output variables in the environment declaration

Tags: serverless-framework

So I have a env.yml file which lets me have a different variables for each stage:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  environment: ${file(env.yml):${opt:stage}}
```

I also need to share some output variables to Lambda which are declared like so:

```
  Outputs:
    UserPoolId:
      Value:
        Ref: QNABUserPool
      Export:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-UserPoolId

    UserPoolClientId:
      Value:
        Ref: QNABUserPoolClient
      Export:
        Name: ${self:provider.stage}-UserPoolClientId
```

I've seen I can do this by adding this to my provider but this conflicts with my env.yml

```
environment:
    COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: ${cf:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}.UserPoolId}
    COGNITO_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID: ${cf:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}.UserPoolClientId}
```

I tried putting these into the env.yml but that didn't work:

**Trying to request a non exported variable from CloudFormation. Stack name: "XXXX-alpha" Requested variable: "UserPoolId".**

I tried using `custom` instead of `environment` and it deployed but the Lambda functions no longer had access to the variables.

So how can I mix these two together?

Thank you so much!

Comment: For now I've added the second environment declaration directly to my authorize function but I will eventually need to find out how to do this for more generic values.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/serverless/comments/lw7lx8/serverless_framework_env_vars_output_vars_together/ has more details

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the `Output` values from your current service using the `Fn::ImportValue` function.

The serverless system adds `sls-[service_name]` to the variable but you can find them in the `Outputs` area of the **CloudFormation Stack**.

Navigate to `CloudFormation` --> `Stacks` --> `[select your service]` --> `Outputs (tab)`.  From there you'll see a column called `Exports name`.

Use that `Exports name` and use that for the import.

e.g. you have a WebSocket service and you need the service endpoint.  If you look in the tab it will have an export ~ `sls-wss-[your_service_name]-[stage]-ServiceEndpointWebsocket`.  Thus, you can import that into an environment variable:

```yaml
Environment:
  Variables:
    ENDPOINT:
      Fn::ImportValue: sls-wss-[your_service_name]-${opt:stage}-ServiceEndpointWebsocket
```